# Trying to access json content and display in a grid fashion

Tags: javascript, json, angular, dom

I have a JSON file having the following content.

```
{
    "rooms":[
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "living",
        "Description": "The living room",
         "backgroundpath":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrsU8tuZWySrSuRYdz72WWFiYaW5PCMIwPAPr_xAIqL-FgmQ4qRw",       
         "Settings": {
          "Sources": [
            {
              "srcname":["DirectTV","AppleTV","Sonos"],
              "iconpath":["src/assets/images/ThemeEditorImgLib_iTVLight5d3a46c1ad5d7796.png","path2"]
            }
            ],
          "hex": "#000"
          }
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "dining",
        "Description": "The Dining room",
        "backgroundpath":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjjspDkQEzbJJ1sSLS2ReWEx5P2ODNQmOtT572OIF9k3HbTGxV",
        "Settings": {
          "Sources": [
            {
              "srcname":["Climate","Shades"],
              "iconpath":["path1","path2"]
            }
            ],
          "hex": "#000"
        }
      }
]
}
```

My HTML file Has:

```
<div class="roww">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">

</div>
 </div>
```

I want to display my JSON content in the HTML. 
So far I have tried the following.

```
private initTileGrid():void
  {

    var col = document.getElementsByClassName("roww")[0];

    var outeritems=this.room_list.rooms;
   // console.log(outeritems);
    for(var i=0;i<outeritems.length;i++){
      var tile = document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 tile no-padding")[0];
     var outerdiv = document.createElement("div");
      var h5 = document.createElement("h5");
      h5.innerHTML = outeritems[i].Description;
      outerdiv.appendChild(h5);
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      p.innerHTML = outeritems[i].name;
      outerdiv.appendChild(p);
     // col.appendChild(outerdiv);
      tile.appendChild(outerdiv);
      var inneritem=outeritems[i].Settings.Sources.srcname;
      console.log(inneritem);
      var innerdiv = document.createElement("div");
      for(var j=0;j<inneritem.length;j++)
      {
        console.log("hi")
        var h5inner = document.createElement("h5");
        h5inner.innerHTML = inneritem.srcname; 
        console.log(h5inner);
        innerdiv.appendChild(h5inner);
      }
tile.appendChild(innerdiv);
    }
```

I am able to display the description and name from the json but not able to fetch the list  of sources.

My final solution should be a grid with number of tiles equal to the number of objects in the JSON, with each tile having a background image from the json and its content.

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Was taking a stab at this and realized your `sources` in the JSON may not be structured correctly. Is the JSON built by you? Also are you using `typescript`? because `private initTileGrid():void` is not right either. `sources` is an array with sub arrays, but it would be better served as an array of `object`

Comment: yes the JSON was built by me, I used a JSON validator online to check my JSON so I assumed it was correct. Yes I am using typescript, I am working on Angular. Could you tell me how to structure it better?

Comment: It is valid JSON. But valid and best fit are different. Want me to post a suggested change below?

Comment: Also is it possible to map an icon(from iconpath) for each srcname?@Bibberty

Comment: @Bibberty Yes that would be really helpful, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V_Stack as discussed, this is just the tweak I would do to the sources section of the JSON, moving forward it will make working with a source easier, especially if you add additional properties. Note it is an array of self contained objects now.

```js
{
  "rooms": [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "living",
      "Description": "The living room",
      "backgroundpath": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrsU8tuZWySrSuRYdz72WWFiYaW5PCMIwPAPr_xAIqL-FgmQ4qRw",
      "Settings": {
        "Sources": [{
            "srcname": "DirectTV",
            "iconpath": "src/assets/images/ThemeEditorImgLib_iTVLight5d3a46c1ad5d7796.png"
          },
          {
            "srcname": "AppleTV",
            "iconpath": "path2"
          },
          {
            "srcname": "Sonos",
            "iconpath": ""
          }
        ],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "dining",
      "Description": "The Dining room",
      "backgroundpath": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjjspDkQEzbJJ1sSLS2ReWEx5P2ODNQmOtT572OIF9k3HbTGxV",
      "Settings": {
        "Sources": [{
            "srcname": "Climate",
            "iconpath": "path1"
          },
          {
            "srcname": "Shades",
            "iconpath": "path2"
          }
        ],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest and **recommend** generating your dynamic HTML the following way with [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const data = {"rooms":[{"id":"1","name":"living","Description":"The living room","backgroundpath":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrsU8tuZWySrSuRYdz72WWFiYaW5PCMIwPAPr_xAIqL-FgmQ4qRw","Settings":{"Sources":[{"srcname":["DirectTV","AppleTV","Sonos"],"iconpath":["src/assets/images/ThemeEditorImgLib_iTVLight5d3a46c1ad5d7796.png","path2"]}],"hex":"#000"}},{"id":"2","name":"dining","Description":"The Dining room","backgroundpath":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjjspDkQEzbJJ1sSLS2ReWEx5P2ODNQmOtT572OIF9k3HbTGxV","Settings":{"Sources":[{"srcname":["Climate","Shades"],"iconpath":["path1","path2"]}],"hex":"#000"}}]}

const res = data.rooms.map(({name, Description, Settings:{Sources}})=>{
  
  const inner = Sources.map(({srcname})=>{
    return srcname.map(src=>`<h5>${src}</h5>`).join("");
  }).join("");

  return `
    <div>
      <h5>${Description}</h5>
      <p>${name}</p>
      <div class="inner">
         ${inner}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}).join("");

document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

```css
body>div{background-color:lightgrey;padding:5px;margin-top:5px}body>div::before{content:"row"}body>div>*{margin-left:10px}h5{background-color:blue;color:white;padding:5px}h5::before{content:"outer h5:: "}p{background-color:purple;color:white;padding:5px}p::before{content:"p:: "}div.inner{padding:5px;background-color:grey}div.inner::before{content:"inner div"}div.inner>h5{background-color:green;color:white}div.inner>h5::before{content:"inner h5:: "}
```

Unminified CSS:

```css
body > div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

body > div::before {
  content: "row";
}

body > div > * {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

h5 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

h5::before {
  content: "outer h5:: "
}

p {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

p::before {
  content: "p:: ";
}

div.inner {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}

div.inner::before {
  content: "inner div";
}

div.inner > h5 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

div.inner > h5::before {
  content: "inner h5:: "
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this method as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem starts at this line `var inneritem=outeritems[i].Settings.Sources.srcname;` `Sources` is an array so you need to access it like `Sources[j]` where j is a number within the arrays length.

The inner loop is fine, you just need to loop through `Sources` properly

I also had to add classes to the tiles class to match your `getElementsByClassName` query

```js
const room_list = {
  "rooms": [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "living",
      "Description": "The living room",
      "backgroundpath": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrsU8tuZWySrSuRYdz72WWFiYaW5PCMIwPAPr_xAIqL-FgmQ4qRw",
      "Settings": {
        "Sources": [{
          "srcname": ["DirectTV", "AppleTV", "Sonos"],
          "iconpath": ["src/assets/images/ThemeEditorImgLib_iTVLight5d3a46c1ad5d7796.png", "path2"]
        }],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "dining",
      "Description": "The Dining room",
      "backgroundpath": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjjspDkQEzbJJ1sSLS2ReWEx5P2ODNQmOtT572OIF9k3HbTGxV",
      "Settings": {
        "Sources": [{
          "srcname": ["Climate", "Shades"],
          "iconpath": ["path1", "path2"]
        }],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    }
  ]
}

var col = document.getElementsByClassName("roww")[0];

var outeritems = room_list.rooms;
// console.log(outeritems);
for (var i = 0; i < outeritems.length; i++) {
  var tile = document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 tile no-padding")[0];
  var outerdiv = document.createElement("div");
  var h5 = document.createElement("h5");
  h5.innerHTML = outeritems[i].Description;
  outerdiv.appendChild(h5);
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = outeritems[i].name;
  outerdiv.appendChild(p);
  // col.appendChild(outerdiv);
  tile.appendChild(outerdiv);
  var inneritems = outeritems[i].Settings.Sources
  var innerdiv = document.createElement("div");
  for (var j = 0; j < inneritems.length; j++) {
    var inneritem = inneritems[j];
    var h5inner = document.createElement("h5");
    h5inner.innerHTML = inneritem.srcname;
    innerdiv.appendChild(h5inner);
  }
  tile.appendChild(innerdiv);
}
```

```html
<div class="roww">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 tile no-padding">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work but it still dosnt get displayed in a grid format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var col = document.getElementsByClassName("roww")[0];

var outeritems = this.room_list.rooms;
// console.log(outeritems);
for (var i = 0; i < outeritems.length; i++) {
  var tile = document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-4")[0];
  var outerdiv = document.createElement("div");
  var h5 = document.createElement("h5");
  h5.innerHTML = outeritems[i].Description;
  outerdiv.appendChild(h5);
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = outeritems[i].name;
  outerdiv.appendChild(p);
  // col.appendChild(outerdiv);
  tile.appendChild(outerdiv);
  outeritems[i].Settings.Sources.forEach(source => {

    var inneritem = source.srcname;
    console.log(inneritem);
    var innerdiv = document.createElement("div");
    for (var j = 0; j < inneritem.length; j++) {
      console.log("hi")
      var h5inner = document.createElement("h5");
      h5inner.innerHTML = inneritem[j];
      console.log(h5inner);
      innerdiv.appendChild(h5inner);
    }
    tile.appendChild(innerdiv);
  });
}
```

}

You need to loop through the `Settings.Sources` and srcname because all of them are arrays